# How to implement an app for existing website

Tags: android, ios

I have a website hosted on godaddy cPanel with mysql database and I am willing to make an app for it. Can anyone tell me how can I do this and please tell me where can I learn more about making an app for a existing website.

Comment: If you NEED an app, i'd avoid cross-platform/hybrid solutions like the plague. They all come with massive downsides and issues. Learning how to build both natively delivers the best results to end users, but this is a huge task. If you are considering wrapping your website up, in the least amount of steps possible just so it can be downloaded from the app store, id question whether you need an app at all

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into cross-platform development if you want to code for both ios and android. Visual Studio is a good tool to work on this, too.
Or, for more simple conversions the below may help:

```
https://www.appypie.com/convert-website-to-mobile-apps
```

https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/convert-website-to-mobile-app
https://appsgeyser.com/blog/convert-website-to-mobile-app-free-software/